# C# Time Management Problem

Tags: c#, time

I am trying to write a program that uses a timer, duration, start time and end time.

In this program it has three screens. When I click start timer on one screen, the other two screens with a timer will automatically update itself. What I currently have is one screen running the timer with the other two screens showing 00:00:00, while the first one is still running. I was wondering If anyone has a suggestion of how to link these three screens together such as if one minute has elapsed it will show 00:01:00 for all three screens instead of just 00:00:00 , 00:00:00 and 00:01:00.

I just need some sort of hint or an idea or what i should look up to solve this problem for myself.

The language I am using is C#

Comment: You're going to have to post some source - its difficult to determine what is going on from just this description.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Do you have three forms with a label each, and all of them are going to show the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a delegate on your timer class.
Each window should then handle the delegate event and update its display if needed.

Example:

```
Timer.TimeChange += form1.OnTimeChange;
Timer.TimeChange += form2.OnTimeChange;
Timer.TimeChange += form3.OnTimeChange;
```

where TimeChange is your timer delegate, and OnTimeChange are the form update method.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to make sure that the timer is isolated from the GUI.  I would suggest building a timer class and having it fire events that the windows will listen for (though you will probably want to limit it to firing the events every so often.)  [MSDN Tutorial on Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx)